# I've mucked up my Visual Studio settings

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have somehow managed to change something in my Visual Studio settings.

I was trying to make some changes to the Debugger so that a project I was working on would allow *Edit and Continue*, and now every time I launch my application VS downloads all of the DLLs for the project from ...Microsoft, I guess.

[image]

This is really irritating, especially because we are behind an old, slow ISA proxy server. I've been waiting for these files to download long enough that I decided to come here to SO and ask the question. Now, I've asked it and VS is still trying to download more DLLs.

**[EDIT]** Here's a screenshot of my Tools > Options... Debugging > Symbols page:

[image]

Also, whenever I run my projects, I can't mouse over the object to get their values because *"the code is optimized."* Any idea how to turn that off?

Comment: Check your Tools->Options, Debugging->Symbols options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One "if all else fails" way to potentially fix it is to go to

```
Tools > Import and Export Settings...
```

There's a "Reset all settings" option.

Now before you do that, you may want to check where your settings are saved.  You can find that here:

```
Tools > Options > Environment > Import and Export Settings
```

See the "Automatically save my settings to this file" setting.  Back up that file somewhere so you don't lose *all* the settings.  After you reset all your settings, you can do a diff on the new setting file with your backed up file, and then you can restore the settings you want.

Comment: Thanks! I'd forgotten about that little gem! I'm glad I made a backup of my settings way back when.